# Apache: Virtual Host configuration

Tags: apache, virtual, host

As i tried to configure my virtual host in apache. I put something like this,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/gift
   ServerName gift.loc  
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my hosts file i put something like this,

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       gift.loc
```

And i run it on the browser,

```
http://gift.loc - is fine
```

But when i tried using this,

```
http://localhost/othersite - can't found
```

Do i missed somehting to configure? ANy ideas...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I found the solution. I put some default directory above the define virtual host block: <VirtualHost *:80> DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs </VirtualHost> this will render all request that do not match to the defined virtual host.

Comment: I wrote this answer if you want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535519/3980729

Answer (score 4):

You need a VirtualHost entry for every host you want apache to handle.  The first one in the config file will be used as the default if no other VirtualHosts match the request.

For example if we have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/gift
   ServerName gift.loc  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot /example/htdocs/gift
   ServerName example.com  
</VirtualHost>
```

A request for foobar.org will get handled by the gift.loc virtual host.

Answer (score 3):

you need to put localhost in the vhosts.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/
       ServerName localhost
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/gift
       ServerName gift.loc  
    </VirtualHost>
```

This works fine (Make sure you restart apache).  If you need to check your configuration you can (on linux at least) run httpd -S.

Answer (score 2):

There are few steps you need to follow to setup the **virtual host on ubuntu**:
Let say that your project folder name is myProject

Step 1:Place your folder inside /var/www/html

```
sudo mv ~/myProject /var/www/html/
```

Step 2: Give ownership of project folder to www-data

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/myProject
```

Step 3:Create new site inside Sites available:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/ 
ls
```

Here you will see existing 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf .Copy the content of both file into one file and replace your folder name or **copy this one into new file named myProject.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myProject/
        ServerName project.com
        ServerAlias www.project.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myProject/
        ServerName project.com
        ServerAlias www.project.com          

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/mobidev_cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/mobidev_key.pem


        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Include the path of self signed certificate also in this as shown ssl key and ssl certificate that can be downloaded easily.

Step 4:Add your project into apache configuration file.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

put this lines in the file:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myProject"
<Directory /var/www/html/myProject/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Step 5:Add your virtual server name (specified in myProject.conf) into host file.add that line:

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1   project.com
```

Step 6:Now all set ,enable site,restart apache

```
sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-availabl/myProject.conf
sudo systemctl reload apache2
sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Just hit project.com in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html), it looks like we need to *create a  block for each different host that you would like to serve*.

Further in the same doc, *If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must also create a  block for the existing host.*

Comment: That would be good to know, but i want gift.loc being served by virtual host, while the 'othersite' is run through 'localhost/othersite' syntax.