# Pointing my domain to concrete5 folder

Tags: content-management-system, concrete, concrete5

I have a domain name, and have installed concrete5 under my public_html folder. So it is public_html/concrete5.4.1 folder. Now how would I redirect my traffice to concrete5 folder ? That is when the user types in www.domainname.com it should show the index.php page from public_html/concrete5.4.1 folder.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this in your server setup (it has nothing to do with concrete5 itself). In Apache, it's called "Virtual Host" (not sure about IIS -- I think it's something similar).
Search around for that term and you will find many many tutorials and instructions on how to do it.
For example: [Apache: Virtual Host configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083681/apache-virtual-host-configuration)