# how to create a virtual host in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 operating system and I want to create a virtual host before starting my php project. If any one can give me the terminal commands I would be grateful.

I have already installed necessary installations and I'm using Symfony php framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create virtual host**

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Enter Password=>

create ip and domain Name=>

```
127.0.0.1    testsite.lk
```

create project folder=>
Go to that directory comand prompt=>

```
sudo chmod -R 777 testsite.lk
```

to asign project to group=>
:~/mayura$

```
> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data testsite.lk/
```

give permission=>
:~/mayura$

```
sudo chmod -R 777 testsite.lk/
```

give document root file for vertual host
:~/mayura$

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

sudo nano testsite.lk.conf
                <VirtualHost *:80>
                    DocumentRoot /home/mayura/project/testsite/web
                    DirectoryIndex index.php
                    ServerName testsite
                    <Directory "/home/mayura/project/testsite/web">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
                    Require all granted
                    </Directory>
                </VirtualHost>
```

Create New project on Netbeans in that folder=>
index.php

Enable the site=>

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

sudo a2ensite testsite.lk.conf
```

Apache reload=>

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Start Browser=>
Run=>

```
xdg-open http://testsite.lk
```

Answer (score 2):

**Open a terminal or a console and write the following commands**

Go to your sites-available apache2 folder with:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

Copy your 000-default.conf to another file (with the name of your site or vhost Preferably)

```
sudo cp 000-default.conf example.conf
```

Open that new file (example.conf) with your best text editor or use:

```
sudo nano example.conf
```

Change the example.conf's content with (Ignore the comments):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mail.com
    ServerName  example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    # example.com is the folder where you have to put your site's code.
    # Obviously, its name can be whatever you want
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    # Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the site as follows:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
```

Restart your apache2 web server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Edit your **/etc/host** file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add at the end of the file, the domain **example.com** and **www.example.com**. It must look like:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
...
# you can replace with your IP
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
...
```

Open your best web browser and write in its address bar: **www.example.com** or **example.com**

Comment: I was gonna downvote this for bumping an old thread, but then I realized the existing answers are abysmal.